# How to set as variable csv column using powershell?

Tags: powershell, csv

I have csv file like this

```
ID Name
4  James
6  John
1  Cathy
```

I want to save those file as .cmd with this format

```
SET NUMBER1=4
SET NUMBER2=6
SET NUMBER3=1
```

The total of ID in the csv file is not always 3. If the ID more than 3, it means my cmd file be like this

```
SET NUMBER1=4
SET NUMBER2=6
SET NUMBER3=1
SET NUMBERN=N
```

Anyone can help please. I really new in powershell, really need help and advice please. Thanks

```
$ID = Import-Csv .\Data.csv | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ID
$ID.Count 

ForEach ( $id in $ID ) {

}
```

I am stuck here

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I updated. I am stuck in that part :(

Comment: this >>> 1ForEach ( $id in $ID )` <<< won't work since the current item $VarName is the same as the _collection $VarName. [*grin*] you need _different names_ in a `foreach` loop. ///// however, that is not what i asked ... _what are you trying to achieve with this?_ what is the _goal_?

Comment: The goal is I can creat a cmd file contain of this ‘SET NUMBER1=4
SET NUMBER2=6
SET NUMBER3=1
SET NUMBERN=N’ its like @f6a4 answer below

Comment: i am well aware of _what_ ... it's the _WHY_ that i am oh-so-curious about. [*grin*] there are ways to set environment vars from inside PoSh ... _but i am so very, very curious as to **why** are you setting those env vars_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
# set current directory to script directory
Set-Location $PSScriptRoot

# import csv-file, delimiter = space
$content = Import-Csv 'test.csv' -Delimiter ' '
$output  = ''

# create output lines
for( $i = 1; $i -le $content.Count; $i++ ) {
    $output += 'SET NUMBER' + $i.ToString() + '=' + $content[$i-1].ID.ToString() + [environment]::NewLine
}

# output to file
$output | Out-File 'result.bat' -Force
```

Comment: it return an error
`You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At D:\folder\script.ps1:48 char:5
+     $output += 'SET NUMBER' + $i.ToString() + '=' + $content[$i-1].ID ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull`

Comment: remove -Delimiter ' '

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach is below if your headers are always present in the file. It doesn't matter what the delimiter is as long as it isn't a number. Your delimited data in the sample is not consistent. Otherwise, `Import-Csv` would be a safer option.

```
$fileData = Get-Content file.csv
$output = for ($i = 1; $i -lt $fileData.count; $i++) {
        "SET NUMBER{0}={1}" -f $i,($fileData[$i] -replace "(?<=^\d+).*")
      }
$output | Out-File file.cmd
```

**Explanation:**

The format operator (`-f`) is used to help construct the output strings. The ID numbers are selected using regex by replacing everything that comes after the beginning digits on each line.

Comment: Hi @AdminOfThings, Thank you for your help. I tried it but the cmd file output be like this : 
`SET NUMBER1="4", James
SET NUMBER2="6",John
SET NUMBER3="1",Cathy`

My expectation only like this
SET NUMBER1=4
SET NUMBER2=6
SET NUMBER3=1